# APNS Push Notification Payload Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, apple-push-notifications

1. Apple says the payload size of the pushed notification is up to 2k(In WWDC 2014), but in my test it still 256 bytes. And i find the office document that still says [256bytes](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html). 
   I don't know why someone says that the payload size is already up to 2k?

   Should i change some setting in my code ? or must set the special properties in payload?
2. If 2k is right,  it still works in iOS7 or lower os version?

(I test this new feature in development certification not production)

Comment: 1) confirmed for production: 2) It's a server side config and works in both ios7 and 8. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26042078/1702413 and https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications/issues/79

Comment: So we can't test the bigger payload size in development environment now?(gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com). And is this new feature can really be used now?(for production). Because apple no release any office document for it.