# UILocalNotifications don't appear on locked screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilocalnotification

I ran my app on my iphone. (Simply connected my phone and chose my iPhone as the target.) I built local notifications in my app which are scheduled and appear perfectly on time on the iPhone. However, they don't appear on the locked screen, even though under Settings -> Notifications -> [my app] -> Show on Lock Screen is turned on.

What is strange is that they even appear in the Notification Centre.

This is similar to [UILocalNotification not showing in the lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050751/uilocalnotification-not-showing-in-the-lock-screen) however I found no answer there either.

Has anybody encountered this? I'm thinking it may be an iOS bug. I'm using the latest iOS, Xcode, OS X to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take permission for show the notification on lock screen ! once look at the code in Appdelegate.swift

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let notificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    let categories = Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>(arrayLiteral: notificationCategory)
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: categories)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    return true
}
```

**Swift 3**

First add **`import UserNotifications`** then add a code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound , .badge]) {(accepted, error) in
            if !accepted {
                print("Notification access denied.")
            }
        }
```

Comment: The `Set(arrayLiteral: )` initializer is not intended to be used directly, it's intended to be used with an array literal. You can just write `[notificationCategory]`. Anyway it's mostly irrelevant now because of Swift 3 :)