# UILocalNotification did not show up when I changed date and time on device in ios8

Tags: ios, ios8, uilocalnotification

I scheduled the Local notification for current day +1 and time say 10AM.When I change the device date to current day+1 and time 10PM then notification didn't show up.

Code is given below:

```
UILocalNotification * localNot = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNot.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"ReminderId", @"REM01", nil];
localNot.alertBody = @"Alarm";

NSString *str =@"10/15/2014 9:15 AM";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];
localNot.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNot.fireDate = date;
localNot.repeatInterval = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNot];
```

Need input.Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know,in iOS8,you must registerUserNotificationSettings first.

Comment: Refer to this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929665/how-to-implement-ios8-interactive-notification/25930069#25930069

Comment: I registered the notification settings in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: Still not working.Need help