# Do UIAlertView have fireDate like UILocalNotifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uilocalnotification

I have a task to create an alarm app. I manage to make the alarm sound using Local Notification.

The problem is that I can't make buttons(actions) on the local notification for "Snooze" and "Okay". I also searched how to implement Interactive Local Notification but I can't follow it. What I'm thinking now is to create an alertView with buttons instead of Local Notification in sounding the alarm. Is there a fireDate function in alertView than I can use to make it happen?

Answer (score 4):

No alertview itself dsnt have any firedata property 
But you went the right direction as when you want UIInteractive Notification to make a interactive notificaiton without the application being opened.

Here is a [link](https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/) to a much easier Objective C tutorial for Interactive Notifications.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and the link for the tutorial. How do I add the category to the payload? 
"aps" : { 
    "alert"    : "Pull down to interact.",
    "category" : "ACTIONABLE"
}

Comment: Just  a quick note here, note that UIAlertView is deprecated and UIAlertController should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

UIAlertView is only used for displaying alerts while the user is using the app. The alert view that's displayed to a user (or, more likely, a banner), is presented by the operating system. You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/) on how to create local notifications with actions. Good luck!

Comment: Just  a quick note here, note that UIAlertView is deprecated and UIAlertController should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

for "How to Implement iOS8 Interactive Notification"
you can check this,
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929665/how-to-implement-ios8-interactive-notification)

Here all the steps are mentioned you want to make local notifications...

Comment: I find the link you give much easier. Thank you!