# Local notification override Remote notification (Actionable notification) setting in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I used following code for remote notification

```
 UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
    action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action1 setTitle:@"REJECT"];
    [action1 setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
    [action1 setDestructive:NO];
    [action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
    action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];////UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground
    [action2 setTitle:@"ACCEPT"];
    [action2 setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
    [action2 setDestructive:NO];
    [action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[action1, action2]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];

    //Right, that is the point
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                                             UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:categories];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    //register to receive notifications
    [UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

This works fine show's correct (Accept/Reject buttons). For some condition i want to wake up app to Foreground so i am using following local notification code in

> - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
>     forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void
>     (^)())completionHandler method.

```
  UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
    action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
    [action1 setTitle:@"LAUNCH"];
    [action1 setIdentifier:@"OPEN_ACTION"];
    [action1 setDestructive:NO];
    [action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:@"LOCAL_NOTIFICATIOn"];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[action1]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[action1]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

    NSSet *categories1 = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings2 = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                                            UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:categories1];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings2];

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    localNotification.alertTitle= @"Security settings enabled,";
    localNotification.alertBody = @"tap the Launch button to start the application";
    localNotification.category = @"LOCAL_NOTIFICATIOn";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Problem: First time Remote notification show's Accept/Reject button correctly but after registering Local notification Remote notification doesn't shows action buttons(Accept/Reject). I can't seen buttons in alerts?

Comment: plz see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929665/how-to-implement-ios8-interactive-notification

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929665/how-to-implement-ios8-interactive-notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remote notification setting overridden by local notification setting.

```
// Registering UIUserNotificationSettings more than once results in previous settings being overwritten.

- (void)registerUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

comment this code:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings2];
```